# Mocker.patch a function when unit testing a Flask blueprint

Tags: python, python-mock

I've got a blueprint file `/views/index.py`:

```
from flask import Blueprint, render_template
index = Blueprint('index', __name__)

def auth():
    return "dog"

@index.route('/')
def index_view():
    return render_template(
        'index.html', user=auth())
```

This is initialized fine from `/main.py`:

```
from flask import Flask
from views.index import index
from views.login import login

app = Flask(__name__)
app.register_blueprint(index)
```

How can I mock the auth() function in my blueprint to return an override like "cat"?

Answer (score 0):

Use the following `/tests/test_root.py`:

```
import sys
from pathlib import Path
sys.path.append(str(Path('.').absolute().parent))

from main import app

def test_index_route(mocker):
    mocker.patch("views.index.auth", return_value="cat")
    response = app.test_client().get('/')
    assert response.status_code == 200
    assert b"cat" in response.data
    assert not b"dog" in response.data
```

Navigate into the /tests/ dir, run `pytest` and this test will pass.